# SDL1.2: How to create text wrapping function with sdl_ttf like in SDL2.0?

Tags: c++, text, sdl

I am trying to create a text wrapper function using SDL1.2 + SDL_TTF. I am aware that SDL2.0 already has a readily available text wrapping function (TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped) but I am using SDL1.2, therefore I am trying to create the wrapping function manually.

Basically I have two surfaces, one which is the wrapper surface and the other one a temporary surface which contains the rendered string. The rendered string is a string between two white spaces taken from the entire string which is to be wrapped. Each temporary surface (string part) is rendered and blit onto the wrapper surface and automatically jumps to the next line if the wrapper width is exceeded.

The string is eventually wrapped properly, however the problem comes with the wrapper surface. Initially I create a colored surface with SDL_CreateRGBSurface() because to my understanding I cannot blit the string parts onto an empty surface. After the wrapping, I want to remove the unused space on the wrapper surface so that the the surface is transparent besides the text.

For this I used color-keying but noticed that that is a poor solution since it also removes some of the text color. My other attempt was to use the alpha values on both surfaces but using SDL_SetAlpha() but this somehow resulted into the same result with the text color being all wrong.

Below is an example of the code I wrote, I would really appreciate some alternative ideas or solutions.

```
TTF_Font* textFont = nullptr;
SDL_Color textColor = {0, 0, 0};

std::string wrapperText = "This text is to be wrapped with transparency";
SDL_Surface* wrapperSurface = nullptr;
SDL_Rect wrapperRect = {0, 0, 160, 50};
std::string tempString = "";
SDL_Surface* tempSurface = nullptr;
SDL_Rect tempRect = {0, 0, 0, 0};

int lineWidthPx = 0;
int lineHeightPx = 0;

int textWidthPx = 0;
int textHeightPx = 0;

std::size_t textBegin = 0;
std::size_t textEnd = 0;

textFont = TTF_OpenFont("res/fonts/Nunito-Black.ttf", 14);

wrapperSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_HWSURFACE, wrapperRect.w, wrapperRect.h, 32, 255, 255, 255, 255);
SDL_SetAlpha(wrapperSurface, SDL_SRCALPHA | SDL_RLEACCEL, SDL_ALPHA_TRANSPARENT);

while (textEnd < wrapperText.size())
{
    textBegin = textEnd + 1;
    textEnd = wrapperText.find(" ", textBegin);

    if (textEnd == std::string::npos)
        textEnd = wrapperText.size(); // Reached end of text

    tempString = wrapperText.substr(textBegin - 1, textEnd - textBegin + 1);
    TTF_SizeText(textFont, tempString.c_str(), &textWidthPx, &textHeightPx);

    lineWidthPx += textWidthPx;
    if (lineWidthPx > wrapperRect.w)
    {
        tempString = wrapperText.substr(textBegin, textEnd - textBegin);
        lineWidthPx = 0 + textWidthPx;
        lineHeightPx += textHeightPx; // Next line

        if (lineHeightPx > wrapperRect.h)
            break; // Text is too large for wrapper
    }

    tempSurface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid(textFont, tempString.c_str(), textColor);
    SDL_SetAlpha(tempSurface, SDL_SRCALPHA | SDL_RLEACCEL, SDL_ALPHA_OPAQUE);
    tempRect = { static_cast<Sint16>(lineWidthPx-textWidthPx), static_cast<Sint16>(lineHeightPx), static_cast<Uint16>(textWidthPx), static_cast<Uint16>(textHeightPx) };
    SDL_BlitSurface(tempSurface, NULL, wrapperSurface, &tempRect);
}

TTF_CloseFont(textFont);
textFont = nullptr;

// Remove temporary surface
SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);
tempSurface = nullptr;
```